# How to tell if glibc is used

Tags: c++, c, glibc

I am trying to implement backtrace functionality for a large framework, which is used for different platforms and OS'es. In some of them, it is linked against glibc, while in the other, something different (eg. uclibc) is used. backtrace() function exists only in the former.

Is there any way to tell whether glibc is used? Any #define? I was unable to find an answer in glibc manual. I know I can't have linking-time information during compilation, but I guess include files have to differ. At least backtrace have to be declared somewhere.
I would like to check it without being forced to pass explicit flags to the compiler.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are the #defines **__GNU_LIBRARY__**, **__GLIBC__** and **__GLIBC_MINOR__** (6, 2 and 11 on my system with glibc-2.11) in features.h.

Answer (score 40):

Include features.h, it contains the macros you need, e.g.

```
#define __GNU_LIBRARY__ 6

/* Major and minor version number of the GNU C library package.  Use
   these macros to test for features in specific releases.  */
#define __GLIBC__       2
#define __GLIBC_MINOR__ 4
```

Comment: 10 seconds is neither here nor there. You get my vote for including snippet from feature.h ;)

Comment: And from me +1 for being a fair loser ;-)

Comment: Thanks drhirsch, you've already got your +1 when I noticed that I was too late.

Comment: In `2.15` there's a nice macro: `__GLIBC_PREREQ(maj, min)` that can check the max and min for you.  Not sure how long it goes back for though.

Comment: `__GLIBC_PREREQ` has existed since 1999-06-18 according to ChangeLog.10 -- I think the first release is then glibc 2.2.

Comment: @MattClarkson FYI: https://reviews.llvm.org/rL322201 https://reviews.llvm.org/D41892

Answer (score 6):

Checking for preprocessor macros is **not** a good solution. uClibc and possibly other libc implementations define macros to mimic glibc (without providing all of its bloated functionality) for much the same reasons that all browsers include "Mozilla" in their User-Agent strings: broken programs that expect to see glibc and turn off lots of features if they don't see it.

Instead you should write a configure script to probe for `backtrace` and use it only if it's available.

Comment: Configure scripts are not a useful solution for a project that needs to build on Windows and iPhone as well as Linux targets.

Comment: @LoganPickup: I don't see why not. But if you insist on using a build system that's not amenable to configure on those targets, you can just have hard-coded configure results (`config.h`, etc.) for them since they're essentially single, tightly-controlled environments.

Comment: Use CMake for multi platform projects. What you want is system introspection, not configure scripts per se. CMake does multi platform system introspection

Comment: @Joakim - CMake is probably one of the worse choices. If he uses CMake he will have to write his own test that configure would perform for him. We just removed CMake as an alternative because it was so anemic, created so much extra work and caused so many problems. For a detailed list of problems see [CMake Removal](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CMake#CMake_Removal).

Answer (score 2):

Empirically, both of the following compile and run fine on GCC 6.4:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
#ifdef __GLIBC__
    puts("__GLIBC__");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

and:

```
int main(void) {
#ifdef __GLIBC__
    puts("__GLIBC__");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

but only the first produces output of course.

This must mean that `__GLIBC__` comes from `stdio.h` which must include `features.h`, see also: [What is the purpose of features.h header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645238/what-is-the-purpose-of-features-h-header)

Therefore, strictly speaking, `__GLIBC__` by itself is not a clear indication that glibc is used, since even without headers, GCC already [embeds runtime objects such as `crt1.o` in the finale executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/52454603#52454603), and those come from glibc.

So the main missing question is: does glibc guarantee that `features.h` gets included by every header? I could not find a clear documentation quote. TODO.

Answer (score 2):

```
#if defined(__GLIBC__) && !defined(__UCLIBC__) && !defined(__MUSL__)
```

This is getting a bit ugly and syntactically ambiguous, but useful.

Comment: To future readers, there is no `__MUSL__` define, see the musl faq for the reasoning behind this.  You're left with probing for functionality at runtime instead.