# libc macro in autoconf

Tags: autoconf, libc

I want to write a macro for finding **libc** . I found that **ldd -version** option can be used for finding version. It is giving a lot of information but i want only version, how to get the version.

```
$ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.12.1-0ubuntu6) 2.12.1
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

Answer (score 0):

For glibc/eglibc you can get this information from `<features.h>` as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266354/how-to-tell-if-glibc-is-used).  Other libc implementations will vary.